# How to use a specific database only for managed operations

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mbeans

We use spring and jpa 2.0
I have managed beans that call the same methods than the client does.
I want the managed beans to run on the slave DB and the client calls on the master DB.

Any idea on how we can do this ?

Thanks

> ```
> Here is my xml file defining datasources :
> ```

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> <!-- connection pool datasource which supports also XA 2 phase commit -->
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/netoplay"/>
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />

    <property name="initialSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/> <!-- The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time, or negative for no limit. -->
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15"/> <!-- The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit. -->
    <property name="minIdle" value="10"/> <!-- The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, without extra ones being created, or zero to create none. -->
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"/> <!-- the idle evicter thread evicts idle connections -->
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000"/> <!-- time a connection may be idle until it can be evicted -->

    <property name="validationQuery" value="/* ping */ SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/> <!-- test the connection using the ping validationQuery before it is given to the application -->
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/> <!-- in addition to testOnBorrow, test connections while they are sitting idle -->

    <!-- If you enable "removeAbandoned" then it is possible that a connection is reclaimed by the pool because it is considered to be abandoned. This mechanism is triggered when (getNumIdle() < 2) and (getNumActive() > getMaxActive() - 3) -->
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/> <!-- Flag to remove abandoned connections if they exceed the removeAbandonedTimout. If set to true a connection is considered abandoned and eligible for removal if it has been idle longer than the removeAbandonedTimeout. Setting this to true can recover db connections from poorly written applications which fail to close a connection. -->
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300"/> <!-- Timeout in seconds before an abandoned connection can be removed. 300 seconds (5 minutes) is the default -->

</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceSlaveDB" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> <!-- connection pool datasource which supports also XA 2 phase commit -->
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/netoplay"/>
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />

    <property name="initialSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/> <!-- The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time, or negative for no limit. -->
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15"/> <!-- The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit. -->
    <property name="minIdle" value="10"/> <!-- The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, without extra ones being created, or zero to create none. -->
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"/> <!-- the idle evicter thread evicts idle connections -->
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000"/> <!-- time a connection may be idle until it can be evicted -->

    <property name="validationQuery" value="/* ping */ SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/> <!-- test the connection using the ping validationQuery before it is given to the application -->
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/> <!-- in addition to testOnBorrow, test connections while they are sitting idle -->

    <!-- If you enable "removeAbandoned" then it is possible that a connection is reclaimed by the pool because it is considered to be abandoned. This mechanism is triggered when (getNumIdle() < 2) and (getNumActive() > getMaxActive() - 3) -->
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/> <!-- Flag to remove abandoned connections if they exceed the removeAbandonedTimout. If set to true a connection is considered abandoned and eligible for removal if it has been idle longer than the removeAbandonedTimeout. Setting this to true can recover db connections from poorly written applications which fail to close a connection. -->
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300"/> <!-- Timeout in seconds before an abandoned connection can be removed. 300 seconds (5 minutes) is the default -->

</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
            <!-- <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/> -->
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
            <!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/> -->
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is my persistence.xml file :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">    
<persistence-unit name="punit"> <!-- transaction-type="JTA" JTA is the defailt --> 
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>           
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Hmm... very easy to decrease the question score, a little bit more difficult to say why or to answer the question.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your persistence.xml definition? Clearly JPA requires a persistence unit and you could have one for master DB and one for slave DB. All well and good criticising people for downvoting, but you've spent minimal time possible on your question.

Comment: I can write here my persistence.xml you will see two datasources defined but my problem is how to tell which one to use without modifying all my methods giving them the datasource as a parameter or to add a bean in all my classes to precise the datasource to use.

Comment: But those are datasources not persistence.xml. In the persistence units you can specify jtaDataSource / nonJtaDataSource (depending on whether using JTA or not) that the respective unit will use (so set them to "dataSource" or "dataSourceSlaveDB"). You present no code for your client or server as to how they get an EMF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background: When you use automatic transaction management, Spring will eventually (usually when you do the first DB access) create a session. At this time, you need to switch between the two databases.

So what you need to do is disable the automatic transaction management and replace it with a manual one. Find the places where code in the client is called and places where the mbeans are invoked. Wrap those with a manual transaction management and create the appropriate session.

Depending on how your code works, this might be a lot of work. The trick is then to identify the side which would need more work. Imagine you have 500 places where mbeans are called but you can install a single HTTP filter for all client calls since that uses HTTP.

So you create a filter that create a session for the client DB and configure that into your HTTP stack. For the mbeans, you use Spring's automatic transaction management which you configure to connect to the slave DB.

Since the normal transaction management doesn't do anything when a session already exists, all code will then go to the correct database.

Note: You can't use automatic caching in this scenario. If you do, objects from both databases will end up in your cache and really horrible things will start to happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these details